# Android SQLite Getting always true when checking if the result exits

Tags: android, sqlite

Im making a login and register system and if need to check if the user already exits so I wrote this function in my database handler to check it.

```
public boolean checkIfUserExits(String username){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE username=" + "\"" + username + "\"";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

But the problem if that i always getting a true.
Thanks for help.

Comment: can you print cursor data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does exist:

From the other function you posted *(it can be accessed in the revision history, so double check before posting stuff, as it will stay around even if you edit it away)*.

```
user = new User(username, password, email);
dbHandler.createUser(user);

if(dbHandler.checkIfUserExits(username) == true){
```

You can just remove the `== true`, that's redundant. Anyway, you create the user, then you check whether it exists. Of course it does, you just created it.

The easy but wrong fix would be to check first, then create the user. Unfortunately, if for some reason two programs do this at the same time, it is very possible they both see the user doesn't exist, and both proceed.

What you probably want to do here would be to try creating the user no matter what, then check whether it worked or not. I dont't know this environment, but for sure you should be able to detect integrity constraint violations.

Comment: I wanted to post two of the functions but it wrote that there is too much code. I switched the the return true and return false and now it works.
Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score -2):

It's posible that your cursor is null and can't count members... My app uses a similar method but it's more complet and can control errors more good.

- Why I pass the complet query? It's simple it's a general method, for a general class. With this you can use this method for all calls and don't need to create a new methods for differents calls... If you need this one for one query, then includes inside how your question.

You can see the code  below:

```
public boolean exists_the_ColumnParameter(String query){
    //Declaration of variables
    Cursor a3 = null;

    try{
        a3 = database.rawQuery(query,null);

        a3.moveToFirst();

        if(a3.getString(0).equals("")){
            a3.close();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            a3.close();
            return true;
        }

    }
    catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        return false;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("-- BDD.exists_the_ColumnParameter --","Exception",ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Comment: It's interessant to take NullPointerException because the app can have problems with 'database.sqlite' file and nullPointerException advice me... I solve a lot of problems thanks this line :)

Comment: a NullPointerException stands for an incorrect programming condition. it's ok to make a Nullcheck if it is possible to have a null value here.

Comment: Exactly, this method catch a null pointer exception when database isNull... I control this when I open app and in 'OnResume' method if BDD is correct but it's possible that any process BDD turn corrupt for example I can know with this catch... It's the only moment that this method can cach a nullPointerException